# Website backend for this website?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, expressionengine, minecraft

I found [this](http://fjordcraft.no/) website some days ago, and I've been thinking about how they do it. Does anyone what kind of back-end they use for everything? Forums, changelog etc. Can't find anything in the codes, and I'm sure they've not made all this by themself.

ExpressionEngine, Twitter Bootstrap and?

Comment: Want you to order site analyzing here? How much can you to pay?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow obsquletaner, I suggest you read the posting guidelines as this post is a little offtopic. (guidelines are under help -> tour)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Their CMS is : ExpressionEngine.

Their Content Delivery Network is : BootstrapCDN, Akamai and jQuery CDN.

Their forum tool looks to be in ExpressionEngine, probably a plugin.

I suggest using [BuiltWith.com](http://builtwith.com/) for these kinds of questions instead on stackoverflow.